# Javascript / jQuery - Mouse events not firing on html added on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding html on the fly with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML += '<a onmouseover="dosomething();">I am a link created on-the-fly</a>';
```

For example the link below:

```
<a onmouseover="dosomething();">I am a link created on-the-fly</a>

<script>

    function dosomething() {
        alert('I am dosomething');
    }

</script>
```

For some reason, the mouse event does not fire and I've tried it with jquery hover event too but it doesn't fire either.

Is this because it's created dynamically after the page way loaded?

If so, how can I make it work?

Comment: Show the code that adds the element, I suspect a quoting problem.

Comment: have you tried adding `href='#'` or `href='javascript:void(0);'`? I know an `achor` without `href` is valid but for testing purposes, it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @imvain2 `href` only matters when clicking, it shouldn't matter for hovering.

Comment: How are you adding this HTML to the page?

Comment: Like this: document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML += '<a onmouseover="dosomething();">I am a link created on-the-fly</a>';

Comment: Remove JQuery title/tag as it's nothing here about it.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5btk8f25/1/ Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("mouseover",".obj",function(){
         alert("done!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="obj" href="#">mouseover</a>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be needed if he's using HTML attributes to attach the event handler.

Comment: no but OP said they tried jQuery and it didn't work. This would solve the JQuery not working part.

Comment: @Bamar I thought events have to be binded to dynamically created elements and that normal attachment won't work.